# Clear data from .txt storage file

Tags: javascript, html

My question is how to clear data from a storage .txt file using a button command in html or possibility using JS to do it as well. My text storage file is called "data.txt" and right now it takes in two variables.

Goal: is to have the ability to delete the two variables from the .txt file using a button from the HTML page.

Comment: no you can't. the filesystem is restricted for security reasons. you can make an ajax request and do it on the server, but not on the client side

Comment: What is the purpose of using this txt file? Can you use local storage or cache instead?

Comment: @TheUknown because my PHP page calls the information from the txt file. The reason i needed the txt file is because the PHP url will be displayed on another computer (same server). Now I need the PHP site to be blank if the user wants it to, so I need to find a way to clear the data in the txt file.

Comment: Hmm. I think you are making this complicated that its supposed to be. Look into alternatives like storing this on server for a user etc. Working with web and trying to make changes on user computer is tricky. Some activeX plugins might help, but i'm not too sure about that. If this is for a homework its cool, but professionally i think its way too much of a hassle and brings a lot of security issues.

Comment: Not sure if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796519/deleting-the-file-from-client-pc-after-upload-but-only-after-client-permission)

Comment: @TheUknown thank you for the link, but I don't want the entire file to be deleted, just the content within

Comment: hmm. sorry man, no idea. goodluck with that though